# file uploaded is a%2520a.docx but browser shows a%252520a.docx

Tags: php, url, xampp

I used php to upload a file  a%2520a.docx to the xampp. The uploaded file I had checked is the same file name,  a%2520a.docx and the path store in DB is the same  a%2520a.docx. I view the file through URL folder%20here/a%2520a but it says 404 page not found. When I view my folder through the browser, it shows the file  a%252520a.docx. Why is there an extra 25 and how should I remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filename must be '[URL encoded](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)'. url_encode transforms any non-standard URL characters into a correct representation (mostly in UTF-8). In this case, your **'%'** character will be transformed into **'%25'**.

Give an eye to this tool : http://www.url-encode-decode.com/

To access your **'a%2520a.docx'** from your browser, you must generate a link which has be processed by url_encode and who returned you **'a%252520a.docx'**